# How can I check for a NullReferenceException in this C# LINQ to XML statement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can I check for a NullReferenceException in this C# LINQ to XML statement without wrapping the whole thing in a try/catch? If any of the properties are null, I would like it to still attempt to get the remaining data.

Thanks.

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("test.xml");

var nodes =
   from node in doc.Elements("Customer")
   select new
   {
       Name = node.Element("FullName").Value,
       Zip = node.Element("ZipCode").Value,
       Active = node.Element("ActiveCustomer").Value,
   };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ternary operator.

[Ternary Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("test.xml");

var nodes =
from node in doc.Elements("Customer")
select new 
{
  Name = node.Element("FullName") !=null ? node.Element("FullName").Value : null,
  Zip = node.Element("ZipCode") !=null ? node.Element("ZipCode").Value : null,
  Active = node.Element("ActiveCustomer") !=null ? node.Element("ActiveCustomer").Value : null
};
```

Comment: Interesting. I haven't seen that type of operator before. So it's like an If Then Else statement, without the If, Then Else. :) Thanks

Comment: yup - very useful in linq

Answer (score 6):

Just use *explicit* cast. It will return `null` if the element wasn't found, won't cause an exception.

```
var nodes =
from node in doc.Elements("Customer")
select new
{
   Name = (string)node.Element("FullName"),
   Zip = (string)node.Element("ZipCode"),
   Active = (string)node.Element("ActiveCustomer"),
};
```

Comment: will it copy its value automatically??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad if there is a value, **yes**

Answer (score 3):

You could try this one:

```
select new
{
    Name = node.Element("FullName")!=null ? node.Element("FullName").Value : null,
    Zip = node.Element("ZipCode")!=null ? node.Element("ZipCode").Value : null,
    Active = node.Element("ActiveCustomer")!=null ? node.Element("ActiveCustomer").Value : null
};
```

The `?` is the conditional operator. For further documentation about this, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

you can use [**ternary operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to check for `null`.

do like this:

```
var nodes =
from node in doc.Elements("Customer")
select new
{
    Name = node.Element("FullName") !=null ? node.Element("FullName").Value : null,
    Zip = node.Element("ZipCode") !=null ? node.Element("ZipCode").Value : null,
    Active = node.Element("ActiveCustomer") !=null ? node.Element("ActiveCustomer").Value : null
};
```